# Is there a way for a function to perform some code to a point and then revert without conditions (more details below...)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I want to create a payable function that acts similarly to onlyowner modifier, or:

```
function owner() public payable{
if(msg.sender != owner)
{
   balances[owner] += msg.value; 
   revert();
}
```

}

What I want to accomplish:
1. when called by anyone except owner function will add funds to owner...
2. and after that it reverts, returning 'unsuccessful' or so.

what REALLY happens though:

1. function is immediately stopped and nothing gets added to owner or anywhere, this of course happens if anyone but the owner calls it

Motivation: looking for a way to create modifier that when gets called stops hacker but adds funds to owner if hacker is dumb enough to send a value with ether to a function called "admin_transfer" which will only contain the owner() function above ...hope this is morally OK from my perspective :). Unless a well intentional user calls 'admin_transfer' on accident which I think is very unusual unless someone looks deeply in the code and tries to exploit it.

Comment: Your goals (1 and 2) are in contradiction with each other. *Revert* means that all state changes are reverted!

Comment: ok so revert remains on top unless it's in a specific loop/condition...but still to the original question: is it possible at all to accomplish my tasks? I am now trying to forward to delegatecall out of desperation...

Comment: Search for honeypots contracts. IMHO real hackers are smart and unlikely to fall to whichever solution you came up with.

Comment: @Ismael: I am not trying to lure hackers on purpose since this is what honeypots do...rather trying to trick the wannabees which is what you just said...